# RGB to x264 : Strange color render

Tags: opengl, video, rgb, x264

i'm trying to make a video from an OpenGl context.

I'm Using glReadPixel, to be sure RGB buffer data is Ok i save it into a bmp file, wich i can read correctly.

My .h264 video is encoded but there are some artefact and i don't understand why.
I tried a lot of different parameters for the x264_param_t but anything better !

Bitmap saved (OpenGL real data) : [Bitmap from OpenGl](http://www.vola.fr/public/video/frame.bmp) (1mo)

Raw h264 with error : [Raw h264 video](http://www.vola.fr/public/video/out.h264) (1mo)

OpenGl ReadPixel :

```
int nSize = ClientHeight * ClientWidth * 3;
GLubyte *inBuff = new GLubyte[nSize];
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glReadPixels(0, 0, ldwidth, ldheight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, inBuff);
```

The params define :

```
x264_param_default(&mX264_param_t);
x264_param_default_preset(&mX264_param_t, "placebo", "film");

mX264_param_t.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGR;
mX264_param_t.i_threads = 6;
mX264_param_t.i_width = mWidth;
mX264_param_t.i_height = mHeight;

mX264_param_t.i_fps_num = mFps;
mX264_param_t.i_fps_den = 1;

// Intra refres:
mX264_param_t.i_keyint_max = mFps;
mX264_param_t.b_intra_refresh = 1;

//Rate control:
mX264_param_t.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
mX264_param_t.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
mX264_param_t.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;

int bps = 5000;
mX264_param_t.rc.i_bitrate = bps;
mX264_param_t.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = bps;
mX264_param_t.i_bframe = 2;
mX264_param_t.i_keyint_min = mFps / 4;
//For streaming:
mX264_param_t.b_repeat_headers = 1;
mX264_param_t.b_annexb = 1;
mX264_param_t.i_log_level = X264_LOG_DEBUG;
x264_param_apply_profile(&mX264_param_t, "baseline");

mpEncoder = x264_encoder_open(&mX264_param_t);
x264_encoder_parameters(mpEncoder, &mX264_param_t);



mpPictureOut = new x264_picture_t();
mpPictureIn = new x264_picture_t();

x264_picture_alloc(mpPictureIn, X264_CSP_BGR | X264_CSP_VFLIP, mWidth, mHeight);
```

Then the encoding loop :

```
mpPictureIn->img.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGR;

mpPictureIn->img.i_plane = 1;
mpPictureIn->img.i_stride[0] = 3 * mWidth;
mpPictureIn->img.plane[0] = rgbframe;

mpPictureIn->i_pts = mFrameCount;
mpPictureIn->i_type = X264_TYPE_AUTO;

mpPictureOut->i_pts = mFrameCount;

int i_nals;
x264_nal_t* nals;
int frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(mpEncoder, &nals, &i_nals, mpPictureIn, mpPictureOut);

if(frame_size > 0)
{
mpFileOut->write_frame(nals[0].p_payload, frame_size, mpPictureOut);
mFrameCount++;
}
```

The write frame :

```
int TVideoFileWriter::write_frame(uint8_t *p_nalu, int i_size, x264_picture_t *p_picture)
{
if(fwrite(p_nalu, i_size, 1, mFileHandle))
    return i_size;
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the color channels needs to be in separate planes?

Comment: I still not sure why you output is broken (ffmpeg decodes it with errors from the first frame). Post what you do in write_frame also. btw here is list of errors / hints that are wrong in your code: 1) no need to call both x264_param_default and x264_param_default_preset (x264_param_default_preset would be enough) 2) i_bitrate doesn't effect anything with CRF 3) i_vbv_max_bitrate wouldn't take effect while you wouldn't specify i_vbv_buffer_size also 4) x264_param_apply_profile will fail with baseline and BGR output 5) you probably need to use x264_picture_init instead of x264_picture_alloc.

Comment: @bofjas : Maybe or not, i don't find correct documentation about libx264 and since i don't have the innate knowledge i'm trying what i can ! nobody555 : Thanks for all theses tips but it doesnt change anything, i edit my first post with the body of write_frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened your output file in text mode (and not binary mode) and so all 0x0A bytes where replaced with 0x0D 0x0A bytes.

Here is your output with this replace reverted: [out_fixed.h264](http://www.sendspace.com/file/7fk6pa)

And it plays fine.

Comment: It was so simple ! Thank you very much ! But it wasn't the last issue ! I change my RGB to YUV, because my final video wasn't like my RGB images. And now i'm trying to synchronise my fps with the different encding speed (if you have any way to help me too !).